# How do I resize the implemented widget to my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, widget

Can anyone help me on how do I resize buymeacoffee.com's widget in HTML, CSS and JS
Here is the current code:

```html
<script data-name="BMC-Widget" data-cfasync="false" src="https://cdnjs.buymeacoffee.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js" data-id="absolutelyazury" data-description="Support me on Buy me a coffee!" data-message="" data-color="#BD5FFF" data-position="left" data-x_margin="15" data-y_margin="15"></script>
```

It takes up half the full screen when the widget shows. I want it to be half the original size. Please help me!

I tried to create a CSS block to make it smaller. CSS code:

```css
.bmc-widget-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 9999;
```

Then tried to add the widget between the class with:

```html
<div class="bmc-widget-container">
        <script data-name="BMC-Widget" data-cfasync="false" src="https://cdnjs.buymeacoffee.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js" data-id="absolutelyazury" data-description="Support me on Buy me a coffee!" data-message="" data-color="#BD5FFF" data-position="left" data-x_margin="18" data-y_margin="18"></script>
    </div>
```

But it ended up leaving a gigantic piece of space on my website

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can resize your widget box.

Currently you are giving css to “.bmc-widget-container”  which is not correct as size of your widget  is coming from “iframe” .

We have to override that using iframe selector.
here in your case we can use ID we get from iframe.

You can give height width according to your needs but make sure to use “!important” as we have to overwrite inline css.

```js
<script data-name="BMC-Widget" data-cfasync="false" src="https://cdnjs.buymeacoffee.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js" data-id="absolutelyazury" data-description="Support me on Buy me a coffee!" data-message="" data-color="#BD5FFF" data-position="left" data-x_margin="15" data-y_margin="15"></script>
```

```css
body #bmc-iframe {  
    height: 400px !important;
    width: 20% !important;
    min-width: 300px !important;
    min-height: unset !important;
    max-width: 420px;
    max-height: 620px;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <div class="bmc-widget-container">
            <script data-name="BMC-Widget" data-cfasync="false" src="https://cdnjs.buymeacoffee.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js" data-id="absolutelyazury" data-description="Support me on Buy me a coffee!" data-message="" data-color="#BD5FFF" data-position="left" data-x_margin="18" data-y_margin="18"></script>
        </div>
</body>
```